# Is there a visual glossary of (Windows) UI controls?

Tags: gui-design, controls, terminology, windows-os, visual-vocabulary

Some days it seems every member of my team calls each control by a different name. Is there a good resource, preferably with images, for what the official name of each control type is? I found a few things but they mostly deal with more confusing controls; I'm looking for something like the difference between a "button", a "menu", and a "tab".

We're working with a .NET application, so Windows-specific terminology would be applicable here.

Comment: I too am looking for a truly visual reference, though the Microsoft glossary is quite useful. Will keep my eye on this thread while I keep searching for one with visual examples alongside definitions. Good question!!

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb328626.aspx

Comment: @PetitHibou72 You mean the same link that's in the accepted answer? Yes, I have :)

Comment: Perhaps the title should be changed to `"Is there a visual glossary of Windows or .NET UI Controls?"`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Adjusted, though I would have accepted something more generic as well. I didn't originally think about the fact that controls go by different names on different OS's

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, here is Microsoft's gallery: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn688966.aspx

Comment: Aha, thanks! I was only finding text descriptions in my own search.

Comment: Sometimes answers get accepted far too quickly after the question has been posted, but I think in this case it's spot on. You couldn't get a better answer than this.

Answer (score 4):

You can also find here for all big company's UI guidelines:

http://usabilitygeek.com/official-usability-user-experience-user-interface-guidelines-from-companies/

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to this link,

http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/user-interface-elements.html